# how to use ManytoManyField in djangorestframework

Tags: python, django, manytomanyfield, django-rest-framework

i'm using djangorestframework. the models one meeting could have many participates. 
So i tried to use ManytoManyField of django:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    participates=models.ManyToManyField(Person)
```

by python `manager.py` sqlall XXX the DB tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE "OA_meeting_participates" (

    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "meeting_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "person_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "OA_person" ("id"),
    UNIQUE ("meeting_id", "person_id")
)
;
CREATE TABLE "OA_meeting" (

    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL,
)
```

the problems comes: when i create a meeting by selecting some persons, server response `'participates'` is an invalid keyword argument for this function. 
since OA_meeting does not have participates field.
so how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see the docs on [manytomany fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#saving-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-fields). You need to create the meeting and person objects separately first, and then do `meeting.partcipates.add(person)`

(btw, i think the word you are looking for is participANts)

Comment: Thanks. i've just tried the .add(), it works.

mt=Meeting(name=...)
mt.save()
mt.participates.add(person)
mt.save()

but in this case, i have to provide a view and crud method manually. Well djangorestframework(http://django-rest-framework.org) is convenient automatically, except with the manytomanyfield model.

Comment: I give up ManytoMayField and use a third Model Meeting_attender to store the m2m relationship.

Comment: have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects